# How do I wire a seven segment LED display to display binary input from two buttons?

Tags: integrated-circuit, power-electronics, oscilloscope, wiring, 7segmentdisplay

I've been tasked with implementing a circuit involving a seven segment LED display and two switches/buttons. One will inject '1' and the other injects '0' into the circuit, and every four inputs a number will be displayed on the seven segment display. The seven segment display will then display the message for two seconds, turn off for one and repeat it two times.

Any advice how to start? I'm have been limited to standard logic gates and latch IC chips, such as D and JK flip flop. I am just looking for help on what IC chips I would reasonably need and how to use them. I've been provided a standard seven segment display as shown in the picture. I've also got standard lab oscilloscopes and voltage providers. [image: seven segment LED as shown]

Edit: Adding on to make it clearer. I have added on a mention to what gates I am limited to. I am also aware on how to wire seven segment LEDs to display numbers based off four button inputs, as well as how to make D flip flop CLK circuits that detect singular inputs and display them on oscilloscopes. I have also been hinted that I need to implement a counter, although that kind is unfortunately lost on me.

Comment: Have you looked at dedicated 7-segment drivers, or a small MCU to do the heavy lifting for you?

Comment: Perfect task for a small microcontroller.

Comment: Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: This sounds like a school assignment. If so, it probably has restrictions that prevent you from doing the obvious (program a microcontroller for the needed functions.)  The images posted suggest a BCD to seven segment decoder.  This implies that you are expected to implement this with logic ICs rather than a microcontroller.

Comment: Use an MCU, probably an arduino if you're inexperienced. There's probably enough GPIO pins (7) to drive each segment separately but it would be neater to use a 7seg decoder chip and save three pins in case you later want to use more pins for other stuff. If this is a school question, though, they probably want you to use Karnaugh maps and gate chips, because doing stuff the way it hasn't been done since before the students were born is good for them, or something.

Comment: Explain your task and the requirements in more detail.  You also need to explain in some detail what you have tried and what ideas you have gathered.  If it is homework, then **you** are supposed to do it - the folks here will help, but they won't do it for you.

Comment: @Dannie:  Because doing it at low level helps you learn about digital logic.

Comment: The question remains, with what you have to implement it? It is very unlikely that you are allowed to implement this with an Arduino and 10 lines of code for example.

Comment: I've been limited to standard IC chips, such as logic gates, and latches, such as JK and D flip flops. I have been hinted that I need to use flip flops to make counters for this circuit, and I know to make a seven segment display numbers from four input switches as well as make CLK circuits that detect singular outputs. I am just unsure how to merge all these ideas together, hence the question.

Comment: @AdamX You really haven't discussed the switches. You say "inject" but this really isn't anything descriptive. All we know is that there are two switches. We don't know if they are momentary, or multipole, or anything much about them and we don't know what "inject" means. If I had to guess (and I do) then I might imagine that they are spring-loaded, momentary, SPST and that there is some kind of serial interface to them where when they are pressed a clock cycle occurs feeding either a 1 or 0 depending upon which switch. But that's a wild guess. Every detail matters.

Comment: @AdamX Right, so there are two pqats. The first part of your spec, about the buttons, is vague in your question but will involve modelling the inputs as an FSM using the flip-flops. The state of the flip-flops will then reflect the number to display with some mapping. The second part is using Karnaugh Maps or Quine-Mckluscy or sth for each segment. As I suggested above, it's worth remembering, this isn't what you'd do in real life, it's because it's "good for you": if you ever need to design combinatorial logic or fsms in future, this will have been a nice, small exercise you can draw on.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an Arduino Nano. It has enough pins and is easily programmable. You shouldn't need any extra components.